# SerialOld GC with G1GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I am using G1GC and in the java mission control I found the following:

[image]

Why it shows SerialOld? In the config it shows the following:
[image]

Comment: Does nobody really have such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is Full GC operation in G1. It used to be serial before JDK 10, it is now parallel after [JEP 307](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/307) was integrated. This is also evident from the duration of those phases: almost 4 seconds, comparing to regular G1 cycles.

See the source: G1 Full GC [used](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/5caa1d5f74c1#l33.7) the [`SerialOldTracer`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/aa16fa44b63f/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcTrace.hpp#l195) for reporting, now it uses [`G1FullTracer`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/5caa1d5f74c1#l63.15). So, before JDK 10 it would have reported "SerialOld" for Full GC, it should now report "G1Full".

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered this is related to Full GC, but for anyone not to familiar with the concept I'll try to clarify:

Full GC only happens if G1GC somehow could not keep up, or something/someone explicitly requested it. Instead of a short (sub-second) mostly concurrent garbage collection you now have an emergency fall-back to classic stop-the-world Garbage Collection that might take many seconds (depending on heap usage).

See for tuning advice e.g.:

[Oracle Java SE version 9 GC Tuning advice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector-tuning.htm#JSGCT-GUID-0DD93225-0BCF-4605-B365-E9833F5BD2FC)

To determine what caused the Full GC you (or anyone else in the same situation) may want to enable GC logging. (E.g.: `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:<file-path>` before Java 9 and as of Java 9: `-Xlog:gc*:file=<file-path>` ). If you do make sure the GC logging is written to fast storage, see: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/02/eliminating-large-jvm-gc-pauses-caused-by-background-io-traffic